# Particle Emitter Editor : the changes are not taken in account in the next builds

Tags: sprite-kit, particles

I have a problem with a resource file, more precisely a `.sks` file, more precisely, a particle emitter.

When I edit it (via the editor), the changes are not taken in account in the next builds!

- Cleaning does not fix the issue.
- Cleaning+Deleting the app on the simulator does not fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to happen only for some properties. For instance, the `speed` property of the `alpha` property, if changed, will not be set to the right value in the next builds.

**Workaround:** change the `angle` property (for instance from `0` to `1` and then back to `0`). In a way, this will tell Xcode : "Hey, wake up, the file has been edited !"